# How to change Strapi port number 1337 to other number?

Tags: server, port, strapi

Recently I tried to use Strapi.

I want run two Strapi apps in single server.
So I tried to change default port number - 1337 to other number (For example 1331)
In ./config/server.js file.

But when I tried to run Strapi, it failed.
In Terminal below is last message, and I can not access admin page - http://localhost:1331/admin

< Opening the admin panel... >

How can I change port number of Strapi?

Answer (score 19):

You can easily change your **.env** file located in the root project directory adding this line:

```
PORT=8082
```

Then save the file, **and run this command in order to refresh up all the things:**

```
npm run build
```

now you can start your server by running:

```
npm run develop
```

Comment: That build did it for me!  Thank you!

Comment: Worked For Me!
You actually don't have to run the build command - just change the port and run strapi app again

Answer (score 4):

You will find option to change the port in `config/server.js`

Please refer official docs link below fore more information.

https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/configurations.html#server

Comment: I tried it already.
But it was useless.
After change port number in config/server.js file, I run Strapi again.
But admin page didn't reply.

Comment: When I created a Strapi project in my MacBook changing config/server.js was working.
But when I created a Strapi project in Cloud server it didn't work.

Comment: Cloud server will have its own port..For example  In Heroku port is assigned dynamically.. So we have to set Host using env variable. instead of hard coding

Comment: In cloud server default setting is working (Not chaning port number in server.js). I have no experience of backend work. I have no idea what I missed.

Comment: Can you share your default setting ?

Comment: I checked cloud platform ACG setting. And I realized I opened TCP port only 1337. After I added another port number, Strapi admin page is working. Thank you. I really appreciate you. Have a great October.

Answer (score 3):

For Strapi v4, this seem to work, might not be the best way.

config/server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env("HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
  port: 1338,
  // port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array("APP_KEYS"),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the port and changed to port: 3000 it worked, but not that much, at least I could show something on the browser, but it wasn't working correctly as it was supposed to work.... then I used: npm run build or yarn build and I have strapi project working well.